JBPM Split does not have a constraint for Connection null
I have created the sample and facing the following error. Can anyone describe why this is happening? I am using jBPM Version 7.
[KBase: defaultKieBase]: Process 'parallelProcess' [testforparallel.parallelProcess]:Node 'null' [3] Split does not have a constraint for Connection null [type=DROOLS_DEFAULT] - Leader [type=DROOLS_DEFAULT].
[KBase: defaultKieBase]: Process 'parallelProcess' [testforparallel.parallelProcess]: Node 'null' [3] Split does not have a constraint for Connection null [type=DROOLS_DEFAULT] - null [type=DROOLS_DEFAULT].

thanks
